# Is the kernel in an integral transform considered as some generalized basis?

Tags: functional-analysis

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform)

> An integral transform is any transform $T$ of the following form:
>   $$
>     (Tf)(u) = \int \limits_{t_1}^{t_2} K(t, u)\, f(t)\, dt
> $$
>   $K: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ is called the kernel function or nucleus of the transform.

Is $\{K(t,), \forall t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ considered as some generalized "basis" of the space for $Tf$?

> Some kernels have an associated inverse kernel $K^{-1}(u, t)$ which (roughly speaking) yields an inverse transform:
>   $$
>     f(t) = \int \limits_{u_1}^{u_2} K^{-1}( u,t )\, (Tf(u))\, du
> $$

Is $\{K^{-1}(,t), \forall t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ considered as some generalized "basis" of the space for $f$?

By "generalized basis", I realize that:

- in a vector space $V$, a basis is defined to be a minimal set of vectors such that every vector in $V$ can be written as linear combination of finitely many vectors in the basis, and
- in a topological vector space $V$, the concept of basis is generalized to be a minimal set of vectors such that every vector in $V$ can be written as convergent series of countably many vectors in the basis.
- here for an integral transform, finite or countable sum is replaced by integral, and each function $f$ and its coordinate function may come from different functional space.

For example, consider Fourier transform FT on $L^p(\mathbb{R}), p \in [1,2]$. Then we have $K(t,u)= e^{-2\pi i tu}$ and $K^{-1}(u,t)= e^{2\pi i tu}$. Is $\{K(t,), \forall t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ considered as some generalized "basis" of  FT($L^p(\mathbb{R})$) or some of its subsets? Is $\{K^{-1}(,t), \forall t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ considered as some generalized "basis" of $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ or some of its subsets? <del>What I have realized is that $\{K(t,), \forall t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ forms an orthonormal set of functions, which is something very similar to a basis.</del>

My questions may sound pointless, but they come from the unnaturalness or discomfort that I have been feeling about integral transforms, and the attempt to relate them to concepts that I feel more natural, such as a basis of a vector space or a TVS, in the hope of deepening my understanding.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: First of all I suggest you restrict yourself to the Hilbertian case $p=2$, otherwise things will soon become too messy. In this setting there is a way to formalize your intuitions and it is called "theory of *generalized eigenfunctions*". You can find more information on [Berezin-Shubin](http://books.google.it/books?id=sU6j9Xdp7uIC&lpg=PP1&hl=it&pg=PA419#v=onepage&q&f=false), *The Schrödinger Equation*.

Comment: My question here is related to your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3171921/71829